# uniform distribution variance problem

Tags: probability

The computer network for a company has two servers.If the time until one server fails is uniform distributed on $[0,20]$, and the other is uniformly distributed on $[0,30]$, what is the variance of the time until at least one of the server fails?

$$\operatorname{var}(x+y)=\operatorname{var}(x) + \operatorname{var}(y) + 2\cdot1\cdot1\cdot \operatorname{cov}(x,y) = \frac{20^2}{12} + \frac{30^2}{12} + 2\cdot1\cdot1\cdot0=\frac{325}{3}$$

Correct answer $28.4$ can someone help figured out what I interpret wrong,and how to approach these type of problems?

Comment: Assuming the servers are both running in parallel initially, the relevant time is $\min \{ X,Y \}$ not $X+Y$.

Comment: how did you come up with min{x,y} please explain

Comment: You're waiting for at least one server to fail; that has happened as soon as $\min \{ X,Y \}$ time has passed. (If $\min \{ X,Y \}=X$ then the first server failed, if it is $Y$ then the second failed.)

Answer (score 1):

Credit: Ian is right that $\min(X,Y)$ is the quantity of interest rather than $X+Y$.

Let $Z=min(X,Y)$ and $z \in (0,20)$,
\begin{align}
Pr(Z \leq z) &= 1- Pr(Z >z) \\
&= 1-Pr(X > z) Pr(Y > z) \\
&= 1- \left(\frac{20-z}{20} \right)\left(\frac{30-z}{30}\right)
\end{align}

$$f_Z(z)= \left(\frac{1}{20} \right)\left(\frac{30-z}{30}\right)+\left(\frac{20-z}{20} \right)\left(\frac{1}{30}\right)=\frac{50-2z}{600}=\frac{25-z}{300}$$

$$\mathbb{E}[Z]=\int_0^{20}zf_Z(z) dz=\int_0^{20}\frac{25z-z^2}{300}dz=\frac1{300}\left(25.\frac{20^2}{2}-\frac{20^3}{3}\right)$$
$$\mathbb{E}[Z^2] = \int_0^{20}z^2f_Z(z) dz=\int_0^{20}\frac{25z^2-z^3}{300}dz=\frac1{300}\left(25.\frac{20^3}{3}-\frac{20^4}{4}\right)$$
Then use the formula:
$$Var [Z]=\mathbb{E}[Z^2]-\mathbb{E}[Z]^2$$

Comment: okay I'm confused on how you got $ f_z(z)$ and why z takes on value from (0,20) only?

Comment: $f_Z(z)$, the pdf is obtained by differentiating $Pr(Z \leq z)$, the CDF. If $z<0$, $Pr(z \leq z)=0$. If $z>20$, $Pr(Z \leq z)=1$. Hence the densities are zero outside $(0,20)$.

Comment: thanks I really appreciate the help,are there any site I can go on to learn more about max and mix of joint distribution?

Comment: what if it was max,how would I find the density function then?

Comment: if $max(X,Y) \leq z$, what can you say about $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: yes,and does this work for other distribution or only uniform?

Comment: if $\max(X,Y) \leq z$, we know that $X \leq z$ and $Y \leq z$. Does this property depend on uniform distribution in particular?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45254/discussion-between-theo-robinson-and-siongthyegoh).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!